# How to get specific numbers from a string in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

i have a tag in the following format: [AAA].[BBB].[CCC Level number]+some other stings here.
for example

```
'[AAA].[BBB].[CCC Level 11].&[DDD3]'
'[AAA].[BBB].[CCC Level 1].&[EEE1]'
```

I want to get the number after Level
so the output of above two examples will be `11` and `1` respectively.
How do you do this in oracle 11g?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `regexp_substr` function:

```
SELECT
  regexp_substr('[AAA].[BBB].[CCC Level 11].&[DDD3]', 'Level ([0-9]*)]', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS val1,
  regexp_substr('[AAA].[BBB].[CCC Level 1].&[EEE1]', 'Level ([0-9]*)]', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS val2
FROM dual;
```

We match any digits that are between `Level[space]` and closing square bracket `]`. The last parameter tells that you want to extract only the first subgroup, where each subgroup is defined by the parentheses - in this situation, we only have one subgroup, which is the number.

You need Oracle 11g for the subgroup extraction, but you've tagged the question with [oracle11g](/questions/tagged/oracle11g) tag so this should work for you.

Output:

```
VAL1 VAL2
---- ----
11   1
```

If it is possible that there will be levels with fractional parts, use this regular expression instead:

`'Level ([0-9.]*)]'`

[Read more about regexp_substr](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions138.htm#SQLRF06303)